# If the default password_hash hash gets updated in php, does this affect future login attempts by a user?

Tags: php, php-password-hash

Let's say you're using the password_hash and password_verify functions that are built into php and using the default hashing algorithm (currently bcrypt). Now, given that this is the default, and if this changes, this would affect the password_verify function in the future, would it not? So, would a programmer need to write code to check for this in the future, ie, if PASSWORD_DEFAULT != bcrypt, use bcrypt to continue the verification process, and then also update the database given the new algorithm?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, changing the algorithm or the cost will not affect password_verify since algorithm and cost is part of the stored hash. If you see specs for password_hash it state

> The used algorithm, cost and salt are returned as part of the hash. Therefore, all information that's needed to verify the hash is included in it. This allows the password_verify() function to verify the hash without needing separate storage for the salt or algorithm information.

You can use password_needs_rehash http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-needs-rehash.php to check if you need to update the stored password. So PHP do already support all of this for you, making hashing the passwords in a secure way easy.

Comment: Looked everywhere for this question/answer. Thanks a lot bud!